# Domain of convergence of $f_n(x)= { {nx^{n-1}} \over {1+x^{2n}} }$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

> What is the domain of convergence of the real functions sequence: $$f_n(x)=
>  { {nx^{n-1}} \over {1+x^{2n}} }$$

I thought about looking at the numerator and denominator and take the intersection of their convergence domain, so I got $\{x<-1 \ or \ -1<x<1 \ or \ x>1\}$. But how do I justify such thing? Or prove it in better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1: $\vert x \vert <1$**
You have $$\vert f_n(x) \vert = \left\vert \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x^{2n}} \right\vert \le \vert nx^{n-1} \vert$$ As the RHS converges to $0$, the sequence $(f_n(x))$ converges pointwise to $0$ in that case.

**Case 2: $\vert x \vert = 1$**
In that case $$\vert f_n(x) \vert = \left\vert \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x^{2n}} \right\vert = \frac{n}{2}.$$ Hence the sequence $(f_n(x))$ diverges.

**Case 3: $\vert x \vert > 1$**
You have $$\vert f_n(x) \vert = \left\vert \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x^{2n}} \right\vert \le \frac{n}{\vert x \vert^{n+1}}$$ As the RHS converges to zero, it is also the case of $(f_n(x))$.

**Conclusion** $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$ for $\vert x \vert \neq 1$ and diverges otherwise.